# Passport JWT & Authorize vs Authenticate

Tags: passport.js, mean-stack, jwt

Passport seems like a great option for simple authentication, unobtrusive and not hard to setup. I'm building a MEAN stack that authenticates using JWT so I looked to Passport JWT. However there's a few things I'm confused about.

1) Am I correct in assuming that Passport JWT is only used for authenticating requests, not for generating a valid jwt? That is, should it only be used for validating the presence of a token?

2) What's the difference between `passport.authorize` and `passport.authenticate`? And when should I use one over the other?

3) I have 3 routes I'm using for authentication related matters, `login`, `signup`, and `authenticate`.

`login` will check if the user email/password combo exists and matches and then generate a token for the client.
`signup` will check to make sure the email doesn't already exist and then generate a token for the client.
Now for `authenticate` this is where I get a little mixed up. Would I even need an `authenticate` route if I already have `login` and `signup`? If anything, it seems like authenticate would be the function that I pass into `passport.use` for the JWT strategy and then `login` and `signup` with the possible addition of a `verify_token` route would be my only unprotected routes, where everything else would have a call to `passport.authenticate` or `passport.authorize`.

Answer (score 10):

1. Correct. Passport JWT (passport-jwt) is only for authenticating requests. You'll need another tool to actually generate a token. [This tutorial](https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-jwt-using-passport/) uses JWT Simple (jwt-simple) and I've used [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) (per [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528377/authenticating-node-api-with-passport-jwt)).
2. I haven't seen any references to `passport.authorize`, so I believe `passport.authenticate` is what you're looking for. `passport.authenticate` is what you'll use in your routes to verify that an incoming request has the JWT token and is allowed.
3. Since you're generating a token via both `login` and `signup`, `authenticate` is redundant and unnecessary. Just make sure you use `passport.authenticate` in your routes to verify access during requests.

The general setup steps to keep in mind here are:

- passport-jwt is for authentication
- you need another tool to create a JWT token
- the JWT token, which you generate and return to whatever made the request, needs to be present in the header (`"Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiO..."`) on subsequent requests
- [you need to setup your JWT strategy and tell passport to use it](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt)
- use `passport.authenticate` to verify access via the JWT token in the header for incoming requests, like:

```js
router.post('/users', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: please help if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044394/how-to-set-jwtfromrequest-i-am-not-using-authorization-here   @user3006381