# Authenticating node API with passport-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to setup JWT authentication using passport-jwt.  I think I've taken the right steps, but a test GET won't succeed and I don't know how to debug it.

Here's what I've done:

1. setup [passport-jwt straight out of the doc](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) as much as possible

   ```
   var jwtOptions = {
       secretOrKey: 'secret',
       issuer: "accounts.examplesoft.com",  // wasn't sure what this was, so i left as defaulted in the doc
       audience: "yoursite.net"   // wasn't sure what this was, so i left as defaulted in the doc
     };

   jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();

   passport.use(new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, done) {
     User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
       if (err) {
           return done(err, false);
       }
       if (user) {
           done(null, user);
       } else {
           done(null, false);
           // or you could create a new account
       }
     });
   }));
   ```
2. Added a token result to my user /login endpoint

   ```
   var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
   // ...

   exports.postLogin = function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
       if (err) throw err;
       if (!user) {
           return res.send({ msg: 'Login incorrect' });
       }
       req.logIn(user, function(err) {
           if (err) throw err;
           var secretOrKey = jwtOptions.secretOrKey;
           var token = jwt.sign(user, secretOrKey, {
               expiresIn: 631139040 // 20 years in seconds
           });
           res.send({ user: user, jwtToken: "JWT " + token });
       });
     })(req, res, next);
   };
   ```

Things were looking good up to here.  I can login a user (using passport local auth) and the response was a I hoped...

> {
>       "user": {
>           "_id": "56c8b5bd80d16ef41ec705dd",
>           "email": "peachy@keen.com",
>           "password": "$2a$10$zd ... etc.",
>           "__v": 0,
>       },
>       "jwtToken": "JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJ .... etc." }

I created an unprotected test route like this...

```
// in my routes file
app.get('/user/tokenTest', user.tokenTest);
```

And in my controller, a simple endpoint...

```
exports.tokenTest = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    res.send("token test!!");
};
```

And GET-ing that works fine, too.

3. But then I try to protect that route like this:

   ```
   app.get('/user/tokenTest', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
       user.tokenTest);
   ```

After I do that, nothing but sadness.  I send a request like this:

```
curl -k 'https://localhost:3443/user/tokenTest' -H 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJ... etc.'
```

And always, always get a 401:

> Unauthorized

Console logs in the controller don't seem to execute, neither does logging in the `passport.use` strategy method.  I've tweaked and tweaked, but I'm a little lost.  The passport-jwt doc just supplies the example, and virtually no other help.

Please, any ideas about either a mistake that I'm making above, or at least how to go about debugging??

Comment: What did you do with the `app.get` route? You say you protected the `app.post` route, but your curl uses the `GET` method.

Comment: @bolav - good catch.  thanks.  i mistakenly protected it as a post route.  changing it to get (see edit), i'm still left with basically the same problem (see updated error).

Comment: @user1272965 I am working on a similar project, can you tell me how do you store the jwt on client-side ? Because we need it in our header for every call to our API, so how did you store it on the client-side ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For any poor soul that follows me here:  the passport-jwt doc implies that the auth header should look like this...

> Authorization: JWT JSON_WEB_TOKEN_STRING.....

That turned out to be misleading (for me, anyway).

Fortunately, thanks to [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token) I was able to learn how the token is built.  (The token's prefix up to the first '.' is the base64 encoding of the scheme.  That "JWT " at the front was noise that prevented the validation from working.

So the fix was to change the token returned by the user controller from:

```
    res.send({ user: user, jwtToken: "JWT " + token });
```

To the simpler:

```
    res.send({ user: user, jwtToken: token });
```

Phew.  Is it me, or is it really a bummer how inadequately these things are explained in so many node package docs??

Comment: Have you tried to use another header parameter through the `fromHeader()` option? I was not able to make it working in any ways...

Comment: this one save me another hours, +1

Comment: You saved me :). was hitting my api with Bearer TOKEN and hitting my head why wasn't it working.

Comment: This must have been some sort of a versioning issue because for me it doesn't work without the `"JWT "` prefix. If in doubt try both I suppose.

Comment: I also need `"JWT "` prefix o_O WHAT THE F%&K I hate dealing with node docs

Comment: I had a different problem. As a newcomer to the RESTful world I got confused about the authorization header. The `passport-jwt` docs state `fromAuthHeader() creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header with the scheme 'JWT'`, why the hell can't they use quotes or something like 'authorization', instead of leaving me wondering which keyword might turn out to be a world standard request header for authorization.

Comment: @user1272965...If you can help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046704/unauthorized-error-401-passport-jwt

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but I had a similar problem, and I have another solution. You can use this `options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT')` to extract the JWT token from authentication header with the following format:

> Authorization: JWT JSON_WEB_TOKEN_STRING.....

Here is the documentation I used: https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt

> Extracting the JWT from the request
>
> There are a number of ways the JWT may be included in a request. In
>   order to remain as flexible as possible the JWT is parsed from the
>   request by a user-supplied callback passed in as the jwtFromRequest
>   parameter. This callback, from now on referred to as an extractor,
>   accepts a request object as an argument and returns the encoded JWT
>   string or null. Included extractors
>
> A number of extractor factory functions are provided in
>   passport-jwt.ExtractJwt. These factory functions return a new
>   extractor configured with the given parameters.
>
> ```
> fromHeader(header_name) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the given http header
> fromBodyField(field_name) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the given body field. You must have a body parser configured in order to use this method.
> fromUrlQueryParameter(param_name) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the given URL query parameter.
> fromAuthHeaderWithScheme(auth_scheme) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header, expecting the scheme to match auth_scheme.
> fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header with the scheme 'bearer'
> fromExtractors([array of extractor functions]) creates a new extractor using an array of extractors provided. Each extractor is attempted in order until one returns a token.
> ```