# Unauthorized: Error 401 passport-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

**passport.js**

```
var jwtOptions = {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
        secretOrKey: config.secret
    }

    var jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function (jwt_payload, done) {
        console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);
        User.findOne(jwt_payload._id, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
            return done(err, false,{error:'its failed'});
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        }
        else {
            done(null, false,{error:'401'});
        }
    });
});

passport.use(jwtLogin);
```

**Authentication.js**

```
function generateToken(user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, key.secret, {
        expiresIn: '1h',
    });
};

function setUserInfo(request) {
    console.log('inside setUserInfoo', request);
    return {
        _id: request._id,
        email: request.email,

    }
};
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('inside login function');
    var userInfo = setUserInfo(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({
        token: generateToken(userInfo), //removed 'JWT' + generrateToken...Reading your answers.
        user: userInfo
    });
};
```

**routes.js**

```
//Assuming every thing is required correctly.

var requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false});

 app.use('/api/contacts', contactRoutes);

    contactRoutes.get('/',requireAuth, function(req,res){
        console.log('inside get route of contacts');
        contactControllers.getContacts(req,res)});

    contactRoutes.post('/', requireAuth, function (req, res) {
        console.log("inside post routes of contacts");
        contactControllers.postContacts(req, res); //logic is correct but generate token syntax is similar to login function one.
    });
```

Service class 
**.ts**

to get the data.

```
getContacts() {
    console.log('Inside getContacts() of service class');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.auth.token);
      console.log('inside promise');

      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/', { headers: headers }).map(res =>
        res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data);
          console.log('inside resolve of service class', data);
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

I am not using Authorization here, Only Authentication.When call `get` post from service class it displays unauthorized.Please help.

In Authentication.js file I have used Token: followed your ans to some post I have removed 'JWT'.But then too 401 Unauthorized error is displayed.

Please help!

Comment: If you really want to be helped, you should put more details about your problem. For instance: `console.log` output and  a dump from your headers.

Answer (score 0):

In your headers.append() located in your service file your asking for Authorization, switch that to Authentication and see if that works

Comment: try combining my answer and the one above so it would look something like headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT', +  this.auth.token);

Comment: just wondering, have you set a user and pwd through the mongo shell for the database that your currently using?

Comment: yes absolutely I have set the user/password even I am able to login this, but when I login the page gives unauthorized.

Comment: meant to say Authentication btw not Authorization in my third answer, but if your logged in to mongo shell than were fine there, whats with those two if statements in passport.js? you should use an else if ^

Answer (score 0):

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + this.auth.token);
```

Comment: What appears in your log?

Comment: 401..unauthorized

Comment: I can see some `console.log` in your code. None of them are never called?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this instead:

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ${this.auth.token}');
```